# How to assign items inside a Model object with Django?

Tags: python, django, models

Is it possible to override values inside a Model?
I am getting **'MyModel' object does not support item assignment.**

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
print my_model.title

if my_model.is_changed:
    my_model['title'] = 'something' # 'MyModel' object does not support item assignment

params = {
        'my_model': my_model,
         ...
    }
return render(request, 'template.html', params)
```

Comment: what is the goal you are trying to achvieve?

Comment: Just to show another title in my template, in case that it's changed. this "another title" fetch other table

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Models are objects, not dictionaries.  Set attributes on them directly:

```
if my_model.is_changed:
    my_model.title = 'something'
```

Or, if the attribute name is dynamic, use `setattr`:

```
attr_name = 'title' # in practice this would be more complex
if my_model.is_changed:
    setattr(my_model, attr_name, 'something')
```

This changes the in-memory copy of the model, but makes no database changes - for that your attribute would have to be a field and you'd have the call the [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) method on `my_model`.  You don't need to do that if you just want to change what the template receives in its context, but just for completeness's sake:

```
if my_model.is_changed:
    my_model.title = 'something'
    my_model.save()
```

Dictionaries are mutable, if you actually have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'title': 'foo'}
# legal
mydict['title'] = 'something'
```

But not everything is a dictionary.

Comment: In general, object attributes are in fact stored as a dictionary (`my_model.__dict__`, for this case) so your intuition isn't far wrong.  But there are very sound reasons not to directly access or edit that dictionary.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I believe that you need to call `.save()` in order to update a django model.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac If you want the edits to be recorded to the database, yes.  I intended my statement in the answer to address that: "This changes the in-memory copy of the model, but makes no database changes - for that your attribute would have to be a field and you'd have the call the `save` method."  Do you think that's missing something?  I'll edit in more info if necessary.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I think your answer is perfect, just a link to some django docs would be the cherry on top! :D I always do that, since more often than not, the docs have all the answers you want.

Comment: I'm saving it, but it's not working? I'm trying to change the value of a field from the form with index 0 in a formset.

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question or find an existing one that discusses editing formset data - it doesn't sound like your situation is as simple as editing an in-memory model instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change values, but this is not how its done. Django Models are Python classes that have models to represent fields. For example a `CharField` is for holding a string in a database. Let me demonstrate ([code from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/)):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

As you can see above the Python class is a custom Django model. It is linked to a databse, and when you run `manage.py syncdb`, it will interact with your database to create the tables and columns that you need it to.

Now, in your case:

```
if my_model.is_changed:
    my_model.title = "Something"
    my_model.save()
```

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks for that, I was editing another question on a on a different forum, so I pasted the wrong thing both there, and here! :P

Answer (score 0):

my_model is an object. So, try this:

```
if my_model.is_changed:
    my_model.title = 'something'
    my_model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

### I was using inlineformset_factory, what I had to do was:

Instead of using `my_model.title = 'something'`,

I had to use `my_model.instance.title = 'something'`

---

***views.py***

```
...

if request.method == "POST":
        formset = modelName2(request.POST, instance=modelName1)
        
        
        
        if formset.is_valid():

            if changeInstance == True:
                models = formset

                # change the title if changeInstance is True
                index = 0
                model = models[index]
                model.instance.title = "something else"
        
                model.save()
        ...
```